# Clever time formatting with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation, formatting

I need help writing a little Regular Expression to replace integers into a time format string in a text input field.

In my form: I have a text input field where I'm supposed to write numbers. And when I write a number: I want a piece of JavaScript to convert it to a human-friendly, readable time when the input field loses focus. The thing that makes this "Clever" is that I want to be able to write as little as absolutely possible: And have it transform to the most appropriate time corresponding to my number.

Let me give you a few examples. If I write:

```
7 it would resolve to 07:00
15 it would resolve to 15:00
93 it would resolve to 09:30
1945 it would resolve to 19:45
143 it would resolve to 14:30
... And so on ...
```

I want it to do this replacement after the input field loses focus (`onblur`-event)

Also. I want to have a 0 prefix for night hours. Like this:

```
015 = 00:15
 03 = 00:30
012 = 00:12 
... And so on ...
```

---

I begun writing if statements to do this, but I stopped dead in my tracks because I realized it would take so many if statements, and would not be very reliable. I feel like Regular Expressions would be much smarter since it compacts my script and makes loading time quicker. I grasp the basics of Regular Expressions, but I don't know how to write a clever one for this purpose.

*This is what my code got to before I decided to drop it:*

```
var elem = document.getElementById("incidentHourStart-" + row);

if (elem.value.length === 1) {
    // Must be a whole hour (0-9)
} else if (elem.value.length === 2) {
    // Can be either two digits hour (10-23) or hour + whole minute (73: 07:30)
    if (parseInt(elem.value) >= 10 && parseInt(elem.value) <= 23) {
        // Two digits, whole hour (10-23)
    } else {
        // First digit is hour, and last one is whole minute (10, 20, 30, 40, 50)   
    }

} else if (elem.value.length === 3) {
    // First digit must be an hour value, middle digit is also hour if it is lower than 23, last digit is then always whole minutes
    if (parseInt(elem.value) >= 10 && parseInt(elem.value) <= 23) {
        // Two digits, whole hour (10-23)
    } else {
        // First digit is hour, and last one is whole minute (10, 20, 30, 40, 50)   
    }
} else if (elem.value.length === 4) {
    // First two digits must be an hour value, last digits is then fine selected minutes

}
```

As you can see: It looks very ugly!

---

**UPDATE:**

As stated in the comments: People have found my rules a little confusing. So here is the pseudo code of rules I want it to follow. If this can be put into a Regex in a clever way: Then awesome! If not: I will write out the `if/else` blocks, or split the Regex up into parts as suggested.

```
If text-length is equal to 1
    Resolve as whole hour between 0-9

    Examples:
        2 = 02:00
        8 = 08:00
        5 = 05:00

If text-length is equal to 2 AND number is between 10 and 23
    Resolve as whole hour between 10-23

    Examples:
        15 = 15:00
        11 = 11:00
        22 = 22:00

If text-length is equal to 2 AND number is NOT between 10 and 23
    Resolve as whole hour and minutes incremented by 10's (10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

    Examples:
        73 = 07:30
        24 = 02:40
        95 = 09:50

If text-length is equal to 3 AND first two numbers are between 10 and 23
    Resolve two first digits as hours and last digit as minutes incremented by 10's (10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

    Examples:
        133 = 13:30
        195 = 19:50
        111 = 11:10
        162 = 16:20

If text-length is equal to 3 AND first two numbers are NOT between 10 and 23
    Resolve first digit as whole hour, and last two as minutes.

    Examples:
        225 = 02:25
        922 = 09:22
        557 = 05:57
        451 = 04:51

If text-length is equal to 1 AND first digit is equal to 0
    Resolve as mid-night

    Example:
        0 = 00:00

If text-length is equal to 2 AND first digit is equal to 0
    Resolve as mid-night + minutes incremented by 10's (10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

    Examples:
        02 = 00:20
        05 = 00:50
        03 = 00:30

If text-length is equal to 3 AND first digit is equal to 0
    Resolve as mid-night + full minutes.

    Examples:
        024 = 00:24
        011 = 00:11
        056 = 00:56

If text-length is equal to 4
    Resolve as regular minutes and hours without the colon (:)

    Examples:
        1524 = 15:24
        2211 = 22:11
```

Comment: You are going to run into a problem when trying to format 121 or 105. Would those translate as "12:10"/"10:50" or "1:21"/"1:05"?

Comment: @KJPrice If that occurs: I want it to convert to 01:21 or 01:05 :) To get to the morning hours: I need to write 1221 or 1005

Comment: But that's not what you have here: "143 it would resove to 14:30". Notice that you decided to make "14" the hours. With the same logic, wouldn't "121" resolve to "12:10"? I recommend thinking through this a little more and be more rigid on the what values you would accept to be translated.

Comment: @KJPrice This is exactly why this is clever! I think a 0 must be added then to get to the night hours. 015 = 00:15 and 03 = 00:30. So then that would make 125 = 12:15 and 123 = 12:30. Separate them with a 0 prefix basically.

Comment: When struggling with such an issue, my **strong** advice is to begin from a pseudo-code algorithm. Then, translating it into JS and seeing if is reliable or not. That's the only way I see if you want to go out this issue.

Comment: @NaveedS If the first two digits are below 23 and above 10: It would resolve as hours between 10-23. If the first digit is above that: First digit is a whole hour, while the last then is whole minutes.

Comment: The problem is that Javascript cannot read your mind. Each and every rule has to be stated and cannot be implied. Take @Zeratops's advice and start with paper and pencil to write up these different rules. To answer your question if this can all be done in regex, the answer is most likely not. Your regex would look much more ugly than 10 `if`/`else` blocks from what I can tell.

Comment: I was with you until you said: "93 it would resolve to 09:30". My question is: why are you making your life so hard? I think you're over thinking it.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. If you want the user to input times, *use an appropriate control that handles time*. So instead of `<input type="text"/>`, you could use `<input type="time"/>`. Otherwise you are going to spend a lot of time with your poorly defined set of rules trying to work through all the exceptions and ambiguities and then realize you've somehow got to explain all that to the users. The fact that fellow programmers here are having trouble understanding your spec ought to give you pause. Oh, and I doubt regex are going to help you much here. It ain't a magic bullet.

Comment: @AariaCarterWeir How would you do it then? :) It all makes perfect sense to me and my colleges. I guess we interpret numbers a little differently here ;)

Comment: @MattBurland That would not work. Since the Time-type is not supported in Firefox or IE: We can't use that.

Comment: @AlexanderJohansen: That was an example (and the easiest one). There are a lot of libraries that have something similar.

Comment: @KJPrice I'm not asking JavaScript to read my mind. But simply follow a set of rules. Granted a little complicated set of rules, and may not make sense to all and everybody since people may read numbers differently.

Comment: @AlexanderJohansen I'm afraid I'm with @MattBurland, if you can't use the  `type="time"` input then for pete's sake just use a dropdown. If you're really, really dead set on this, help me out by posting some pseudo code showing exactly how your rules work :) x

Comment: @AariaCarterWeir Posted my pseudo-code. The whole idea of this is to make form input as quick as possible. Since my co-workers need to input data quickly and efficiently. Using dropdown-boxes will make it "clunky". in my personal opinion at least.

Comment: Still need help? I'll give this a shot.

Comment: @AariaCarterWeir Well. I did write my `if/else` code out and it works flawlessly! :) But since StackOverflow doesn't let me post my answer: I neglected it. I'll try it again later. But If you can write something that is smarter: I would love to see it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution and had it deployed for about 1.5 months now. And so far: It works great. My co-workers love this functionality, and really saves up a lot of time! So far: No faults have been reported to me.

---

### So here is what I did:

I bascially re-wrote my pseudo-code into actual JavaScript code using `if/else` blocks as suggested in the question's comments. I stuck it all into a function that I call from an [onblur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) event on the input fields. Like this:

```
<input type="text" id="incidentHourStart-1" onblur="resolveTimeField(1);">
```

So the formatting occurs as soon as the input field loses focus.

Here is what my function looks like:

```
function resolveTimeField(row) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("incidentHourStart-" + row);

    if (elem.value.length === 1) {

        // Must be a whole hour (0-9)
        elem.value = "0" + elem.value + ":00";

    } else if (elem.value.length === 2) {

        // Can be either two digits hour (10-23) or hour + whole minute (73: 07:30)
        if (parseInt(elem.value) >= 10 && parseInt(elem.value) <= 23) {
            // Two digits, whole hour (10-23)
            elem.value = elem.value + ":00";
        } else {
            // First digit is hour, and last one is whole minute (10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

            var hours = elem.value.substring(0, 1);
            var minutes = elem.value.substring(1, 2);
            elem.value = "0" + hours + ":" + minutes + "0";

        }
    } else if (elem.value.length === 3) {

        // First digit must be an hour value, middle digit is also hour if it is lower than 23, last digit is then always whole minutes
        var firstDigits = elem.value.substring(0, 2);

        if (parseInt(firstDigits) >= 10 && parseInt(firstDigits) <= 23) {

            // 3 digits, first two are hours, and last digit is minutes incremented by 10's
            var hours = elem.value.substring(0, 2);
            var minutes = elem.value.substring(2, 3);
            elem.value = hours + ":" + minutes + "0";

        } else {

            // First digit is hour, and last two is full minutes
            var hours = elem.value.substring(0, 1);
            var minutes = elem.value.substring(1, 3);
            elem.value = "0" + hours + ":" + minutes;

        }
    } else if (elem.value.length === 4) {

        // First two digits must be an hour value, last digits is then fine selected minutes
        var hours = elem.value.substring(0, 2);
        var minutes = elem.value.substring(2, 4);
        elem.value = hours + ":" + minutes;

    }
}
```

**Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/92zgwcee/) if you want to test out the code for yourself**

My function takes one parameter referenced as `row`. This is because the fields I am working with lays within a dynamic table that lets my co-workers register more data in one go.

Currently it does not have any forms of input validation that checks if the inserted value is valid. So you could write something like `999` into the field and have it resolve to `09:99`. This is not a critical feature for our environment, but I can imagine it would be fairly easy to implement shall it be required. I will update this post if I ever implement such a validation feature in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it harder on yourself than you need. Simply put; don't do this in one regular expression. Also don't forget to trim your input before using RegEx.

First of all check the zero-prefixed one, something like:

```
^0(\d+)$
```

Then if that doesn't match, do the check for the normal numbering and split it with the capture groups however you want:

```
^([^0]\d{1,3})$ // Can do negative lookbehind here, but I left it simple in this case
```

Regular expressions are often misused to solve a bigger problem in one pattern. It's much better to split logic if the situation asks for it. Don't overcomplicate code. It will break whoever needs to read it later's brain.

Comment: You make some excellent points here. I will try breaking it up in parts and see what I can work with.